# Remove a Distribution List Owner via powershell

Tags: powershell

If I run the script to add a new admin to a DL, it works fine:

```
$dl = 'dl@abc.com'
$Admin = 'admin@abc.com'
Set-DistributionGroup $dl -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -ManagedBy((Get-DistributionGroup $dl).ManagedBy + $Admin)
```

But If I run this script to remove an admin it fails. I believe this worked in the past.
The error I get is "does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'"

```
Set-DistributionGroup $dl -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -ManagedBy((Get-DistributionGroup $dl).ManagedBy – $Admin)
```

How can I use powershell to remove an admin from a DL?
Thanks

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/poshchap/remove-a-string-from-a-multi-valued-attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/poshchap/remove-a-string-from-a-multi-valued-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

Use `@{Remove=$Admin}`

e.g.

```
Set-DistributionGroup $dl -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -ManagedBy @{Remove=$Admin}
```

Comment: I get an error "the term remove is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..."

Comment: I ran the exact same commands in my tenant and it worked.  You might want to confirm that the account you are using has sufficient permissions to edit DL owners.  Often times when powershell says "thats not a recognized cmdlet" or "thats not a recognized parameter", its because your session won't 'see' cmdlets or parameters that you dont have permissions to run.  Also, are you doing this in Exchange Online or on-prem?

Comment: Yes I have the rights to edit DL owners. I am doing this via Exchange on-prem (We have a hybrid environment)

Comment: I tested this on EXO, but by everything I can tell this should work in on-prem too, all the way back to Exchange 2010.  The documentation basically says to do it the same way "-ManagedBy @{Remove=$Admin}".  Scroll down to the section for "-ManagedBy" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/set-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps
Im still thinking this is permission related.  Can you prove me wrong by trying to add a single user to managedby?  e.g  Set-DistributionGroup $dl -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -ManagedBy $Admin

Comment: this script works fine Set-DistributionGroup $dl -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -ManagedBy((Get-DistributionGroup $dl).ManagedBy + $Admin). I also mentioned it in the initial post. I believe you are running your script in the cloud, which may probably work fine there. Try running the same script on your on-prem environment and see if it works.